# why is the following thing a projection operator?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T: E \rightarrow E$ be an endomorphism of a finite-dimensional vector space, and let $S$ be a circle in the complex plane that does not intersect any eigenvalues of $T$. Now let $Q = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_S (z-T)^{-1} \, dz$.

Why is $Q$ a projection operator?

The motivation behind this question is that the above situation occurs in a proof of Bott's periodicity theorem, but it's not clear to me that $Q$ is a projection...

Comment: (This has nothing to do with k-theory, by the way.)

Comment: (You're right, but I figured that if anyone else read Atiyah's proof in his book, then they may have come across this issue as well. I'll remove the tag.) (Parenthetical conversations feel like whispering.)

Comment: I would definitively use the tag (functional-analysis)

Answer (score 4):

If $A$ is any Banach algebra (such as the algebra of endomorphisms of a finite dimensional  complex vector space), then for each subset $\Omega$ of the complex plane and each element $T$ of $A$ whose spectrum is contained in $\Omega$, [holomorphic functional calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_functional_calculus) yields a homomorphism $f\mapsto f(T)$ from the algebra of functions holomorphic in an open set containing $\Omega$ (identified if they agree on some neighborhood of $\Omega$) into $A$.  Since the function $f:(\mathbb{C}\setminus S)\to\mathbb{C}$ defined by $f(w)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_S(z-w)^{-1}dz$ takes on only the values $0$ and $1$ (it gives the winding number of $S$ about $w$), $f$ is idempotent (i.e., $f(w)^2=f(w)$ for all $w\in\mathbb{C}\setminus S$), and thus $f(T)$ is an idempotent element of $A$ for each $T$ whose spectrum is disjoint from $S$.

Comment: ooooh... I like both of these answers equally. I don't know which one to accept...

Comment: And am I to understand "0" and "1" as the 0 map E --> E and the identity on E? Also, I assume that the verification that the fact that this winding number acts like the more familiar winding number is relatively straightforward...

Comment: @Dylan: Sorry for the lack of clarity.  By $f(w)$ I meant that $w$ is in $\mathbb{C}\setminus S$, and $f:\mathbb{C}\setminus S\to \mathbb{C}$ is the ordinary winding number.  So $f$ is a plain old function of a complex variable, where the operations are pointwise.  Its values are the complex numbers $0$ and $1$, hence it equals its (pointwise) square.  The homomorphism property of holomorphic functional calculus then guarantees that $f(T)^2=f(T)$.  I have edited to clarify.

Comment: @Dylan: But there is certainly work involved in verifying the relevant properties of holomorphic functional calculus for Banach algebras, and this approach to your particular problem is probably overkill.

Comment: Ah! Now I understand... very clever, and very helpful intuitively. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Show that the integral depends continuously on $T$, and show that $Q^2=Q$ when $T$ is diagonalizable, by finding how $Q$ changes change you change $T$ by a similar matrix, and then reducing to the one dimensional case. Then use the fact that diagonalizable matrices are dense in the space of all matrices, and that $Q^2$ and $Q$ are continuous functions of $Q$.

Comment: huh... so it seems like this is fairly nontrivial? I thought I was just being dumb since Atiyah just defines Q and then says, "which is a projection operator that commutes with T." Thanks!

Comment: Also I think you mean T at the very end

Comment: "Trivial" is a relative notion! (I mean $Q$, but I also have in mind the fact that the composition of continuous functions is continuous :) )

Comment: @Dylan: by the way, can you see what is the subspace $Q$ projects on to?

Comment: Ah, for that I think Jonas's answer gives it away... I think that its image should contain all the eigenvectors corresponding to eigenvalues of T inside S?